# Can fleet units charge the turn they run

Tags: warhammer-40k, tyranids

So the warhammer 40k rule book is pretty explicit about running and charging not being allowed but I was wondering if their was possibly a errata I was missing about fleet units being able to charge the turn they run? In previous editions you could run and charge if you had fleet and this makes my hormagaunts rather horrible when I fleet right in front of the opponent. Maybe this is why I have read that Tyranids are not as good in the new rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not unless there is a formation/codex specific rule that allows it.

Under the current 7th ed rules, Fleet is a re-roll to either your Run or Charge moves.

It sucks.

Comment: FWIW if you do get a rule that says you can run AND charge, Fleet applies to both rolls.